# How to prevent Angular rendering component in new tab

Tags: angular

I have an Angular component that should be rendered only once, on the first screen of the app, and not every time I open a tab.

Using `localStorage` to mark the component as active is a bit problematic since one can close the browser and it will be hard to track that.

Comment: `Using localStorage to mark the component as active is a bit problematic since one can close the browser and it will be hard to track that.` can you elaborate more?

Comment: Sounds like you are confusing sessionStorage with localStorage. The latter is persistent when browser closes

Comment: Are you using any ui component librabry?

Comment: It would be helpful, when you provide some code

Comment: I am using Material design

Comment: @charlietfl both will not help in this case, as I need to make sure that my component is opened on one tab and only this one.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using *ngIf to hide your component it's very logic that angular renders the component in every time you open the tab try to use :
 `[hidden]="!expression"` instead of `*ngIf="expression"`